# Redis: Is there a way to get a difference of Keyspace

Tags: redis

info keyspace

Its currently incremental and purged at end of month . But i want to have per day between mentioned time for some kpi analysis .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a cron job of:

```
redis-cli -h host -p port info keyspace | grep db0 | sed 's/.*keys=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/' | xargs redis-cli -h host -p port set metric:keys:$(date "+%y-%m-%d-%H")
```

This will get you a set of keys in Redis with metrics at specific hour.

> ~$ redis-cli -h host -p port get metric:keys:18-06-15-12
>   "25"

This one-liner will get keyspace info, filter info for db0 (change for any other you interested in), extract the number, send back to Redis as a metric. You also can change that to a hash so metric itself won't change your number. But for 1m+ instances a couple of keys won't matter. Or you can store them in another db if you want.

Comment: Thanks for above . It just get the keys at different times , but i need to calculate the difference of keys between hours again separately which i can do . But is there a way to just get the difference directly . get metric:keys:18-06-15-12 25 get metric:keys:18-06-15-13 40 . but is there a way to get that at time 18-06-15-13 it is 15

Comment: After you set up this cron to collect metrics, you can issue two get commands and compare results. You can even pack it in an eval call `redis-cli -h host -p port eval "local new=redis.call('get','metric:keys:'..KEYS[1]) local old=redis.call('get','metric:keys:'..KEYS[2]) return (new-old)" 2 18-06-15-15 18-06-15-12`